# how to update value in one column and automaticaly updated another column at different table laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, crud

i try to update value of name in table student and auto updated in column name at table users

my controller code is

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
    { 
        $user = User::where('id', $id)->first();
        $user->name = $request->name;
        $user->save();

        $student= Student::where('id', $id)->first();
        $student->name = $request->name;
        $student->save();

       return redirect()->route('profilestudent.edit', Auth::user()->student->id);
   }
```

no errors but it change another user's name at table users.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with [mutators](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-a-mutator):

```
class User extends Model
{
    public function setNameAttribute($value)
    {
        $student= Student::where('user_id', $this->id)->first() if id is not key in Student
        $student->name = $value;
        $student->save();
        $this->attributes['first_name'] = $value;
    }
}
```

Comment: i didnt get it, should i make a new function?

Comment: @kuntet please check the documentation i've linked, in poor words this function will be inkoved every time you assign something to name of user

Comment: @kuntet and then in the controller you just need to set the user name and not both

Answer (score 0):

You should use the observers. When a User is updated, the Student will automatically also being updated.